# Python convert Json string values to int float boolean

Tags: python, json

**Objective:**
I am coming from javascript background. I am try to parse a json.
`json.loads` is supposed to convert stringfied values into their relevant type.

How can it be done with python 3? Purpose is eval all values with relevant type.

**Scenerio:**
I am reading csv in python 
when reading csv, values are converted to strings
I removed csv code becuase it was not relevant  !!!

**Code:**

```
import json
x = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "dev":"true", "trig":"1.0E-10", "res":"0.1"}'
y = json.loads(x)
print(y)
```

**Current Output:**

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30", 
  "dev": "true", 
  "trig": "1.0E-10", 
  "res": "0.1"
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,       // int 
  "dev": true,     //  bool
  "trig": 1.0E-10, // real number
  "res": 0.1       // float
}
```

Comment: In your JSON input you have quotes around `true` and `1.0E-10` and `0.1`. That makes them strings. It would be the same if you were loading the same JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: No , they are evaluated BTW. But consider i am reading csv and i want values to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that your json data contains strings, not values (e.g. `"dev":"true"` instead of `"dev":true`).  Parsing the string in javascript will hit the same problems you're seeing in Python:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp> node
> x = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "dev":"true", "trig":"1.0E-10", "res":"0.1"}'
'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "dev":"true", "trig":"1.0E-10", "res":"0.1"}'
> JSON.parse(x)
{ name: 'John', age: 30, dev: 'true', trig: '1.0E-10', res: '0.1' }
> JSON.parse(x).dev
'true'
> typeof JSON.parse(x).dev
'string'
```

The real solution here is to fix whatever is creating such malformed json.

You can hack your way around it in Python by e.g.:

```
import ast, json

x = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "dev":"true", "trig":"1.0E-10", "res":"0.1"}'

def evalfn(pairs):
    res = {}
    for key, val in pairs:
        if val in {'true','false'}:
            res[key] = val == 'true'
            continue
        try:
            res[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)
        except Exception as e:
            res[key] = val
    return res

y = json.loads(x, object_pairs_hook=evalfn)
print y
```

which will print

```
{u'trig': 1e-10, u'res': 0.1, u'age': 30, u'name': u'John', u'dev': True}
```

Comment: Thankx. It works. But what should be standard practive when reading csv files , as csv reader converts every value to string

Comment: That sounds like something you should ask in a new question, but normally you'll know the data types for each column when you're parsing csv by hand (it's still a very manual process). All the "cool kids" seem to be using pandas for such things these days though, and it has a much more sophisticated csv parser (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thankx yes i know a bit about pandas, but i was more curious about vanilla way. Your solution is very helpful. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

First you need to load your json from file

```
file = open('data.json', 'r')
content = file.read()
file.close()
```

Then we can go over each value and check whether we can convert it to `int` or `float` or if its either `'true'` or `'false'`, if so we update specific value of our dictionary.

```
import json

loaded_json = json.loads(content)

def is_type(x, t):
    try:
        t(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

for k, v in loaded_json.items():
    if is_type(v, int):
        loaded_json[k] = int(v)
    elif is_type(v, float):
        loaded_json[k] = float(v)
    elif v == 'true':
        loaded_json[k] = True
    elif v == 'false':
        loaded_json[k] = False

for k, v in sorted(loaded_json.items()):
    print(k, v, '//', type(v))
```

**Output:**

```
age 30 // <class 'int'>
dev True // <class 'bool'>
name John // <class 'str'>
res 0.1 // <class 'float'>
trig 1e-10 // <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Thankx , I have 2 questions, How can i do it with json_loads hook
2nd - should json_loads not suport it by defualt, how can i use ```parse_int``` option mentioned in docs

Comment: Since your values are in quotation marks `"` they are being interpreted as strings, if your values wouldn't have them they would be loaded as their corresponding types. I never used object_hook or parse_int arguments.